# How to implement antd Popconfirm onKeyDown event

Tags: antd, onkeydown

I need to fire Popconfirm message not only when clicked on the Cancel button, but when pressed on Esc button on keyboard as well. Antd provides out of the box solution for onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave, onFocus, onClick events.https://ant.design/components/popconfirm/

How to pass onKeyDown event to a child node of the Popconfirm component?

```
<Popconfirm
   title={message}
   placement='top'
   onConfirm={handleConfirm}
>
    <Button>{'Cancel'}</Button>
</Popconfirm>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Popconfirm` is a child of the `Tooltip` component (https://ant.design/components/tooltip/#API) which has the `visible` prop. With that, you can handle the visibility state outside of your Popconfirm, for example in a wrapping component, which also listenes to the key event.

Something like that should work:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {Popconfirm} from "antd";

const PopconfirmWrapper = ({children, message, onConfirm}) => {
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
    return <Popconfirm
        onKeyDown={() => /* maybe check the key first? */ setVisible(true)}
        title={message}
        placement='top'
        onConfirm={onConfirm}
        onVisibleChange={() => setVisible(!visible)}>
        {children}
    </Popconfirm>
}

export default PopconfirmWrapper;
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but the thing is onKeyDown is not included in Tooltip or Popconfirm props..

Comment: Did you try it out? onKeyDown is one of React's standard events, that should work on every node. If it doesn't work on Popconfirm, please wrap it into a ``<div onKeyDown={() => {}}>``.
See: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html